# Can be SAS congruence theorem applied on single triangle?

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be isosceles triangle with base $BC$. We know that $|AB|=|AC|$, $|AC|=|AB|$ and $|\angle BAC|=|\angle CAB|$, so can we say, that triangles $ABC$ and $ACB$ are congruent and thus $|\angle ABC|=|\angle ACB|$? Is this valid way to prove that angles opposite to two equal sides of a triangle are equal?

Comment: Yes, that is valid.

Comment: That's how [Pappus proved it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pons_asinorum#Pappus)!